# To sum SPECIFIC number of cell values based on criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

**I have a list**

[image]

How to calculate the sum of "amount" from **Top 5 blank**(unpaid) cells? In this case, it would be `13,5,13,11,4`. I don't want to change cell range every time Blank cell are changed to Paid.
My real problem is very different than this, but if this has a solution, I can probably work on that.

Comment: You are asking for a fairly complex database operation.  You should look into using pivot tables or VBA to handle this.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I was just hoping if someone knew this

Comment: There probably is a way to do this with pure Excel, at least part of it.  I upvoted your question and maybe a guru will give you an answer.

Comment: If not from the bottom, can we add values from top 5 unpaid cells?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that looks like a challenge!

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald Sadly my Excel isn't strong enough to handle this.  I could do it with pivot tables though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a couple of "Helper" columns:

- an ISBLANK() formula testing column B
- a COUNTIF() where column C is TRUE from the top of column C down to the adjacent column C cell.

Assuming Amount in column A and Paid/Unpaid in column B, starting from row 4 then:

- in C4, `=COUNTIF($C$4:C4,TRUE)` and copied down to last row
- in D4, `=SUMPRODUCT(($C$4:C4)*($A$4:A4)*(($D$4:D4)<NumberToSum+1))` also copied down.

Added bonus: 'NumberToSum' is a named range in F1 where you can enter a number.

Image below may help to illustrate
[image: Sumproduct with variable range and user criteria]

Note that for completeness, E3 should have a formula '="Sum of 1st " & NumberToSum &" Unpaid"' to display the number being summed.